# Passcode alarm with standby blinking led

Tags: led, digital-logic, homework

I’m trying to design a basic 4 digit code alarm. If the 4 inputs match the key code then an led will turn on and if they don’t, an alarm will go off. I have this solved, the problem is that I have to add an led that blinks until 4 digits are inputted. I know it might be kinda silly but I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I didn't explain what I am trying to do properly so here it goes. I am trying to design a circuit that works as an alarm. The inputs are only highs or lows. As shown in the image below, the Digital Writer has 8 different diodes. diodes 7-4 are the set keycode being 7 the msb and 4 the lsb. Diode 3 does not have any use. Diode 2 will work as a clock, everytime i toggle it it will input whichever value 1 is on. Lastly, 0 will work as a reset button. If the user inputs 2 of the values and decides to start over, presing the reset button will re start the sequence of binary digits. If the sequence of highs and lows matches the key code then the green LED will turn on, if not the red LED will turn on. Before the user inputs the entire code, there will be a flashing LED (not included in any of the images) and it will stop flashing and turn off when any 4 values have been inputted, does not matter if they're correct or not. This might be very easy for most of you but I'm just in my third semester of college and Im really struggling with it. Thanks again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would really help to see how you've designed this up to the point that you have it.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: I added what I have done, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: um, can you explain how this lets you input a *sequence of four digits*?

Comment: Its just a high or low type of situation, it is very simple.

Comment: Yes, what doe s the user actually do when they **input** a digit?

Comment: OK, how do you know when a user has **input** a digit rather than just leaving the digit where it was?

Comment: I'm currently opening or closing the swithces. The top 4 switches are the key code and the bottom 4 are the inputs.

Comment: Can you edit again to write the problem you were asked to solve. Quote it exactly.

Comment: I am going to connect it to a digital writer where diodes 7-4 are the key code and then i set diode 1 to high or low and submit it by togging diode 2.

Comment: (1) Don't bury important information in the comments. [Edit] it into the question. (2) What is a "digital writer"?

Comment: @Transistor I updated the question

Comment: And we still don't have the wording of the assignment you have been given. Most of us suspect that you have designed an incorrect solution to the problem you have been assigned. "*Diode 3 does not have any use. Diode 2 will work as a clock, ...*" Diodes 3 and 2 don't exist in your schematic. The only diodes are labelled 'S5' to 'S7'.

Comment: The diodes are the switches in the digital writer, that is how they're called.

Comment: Luis, please read back through **all** the comments and try and answer the points raised. You still haven't given the actual assignment. I looked up [digital writer](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/372500F-01/372500f/elvisexpress_digital_writer/) and I suspect that your "diode" is the reference to DIO which means "Digital Input Output", not diode. You now have two schematics in your question but you didn't explain why.